# mcustomscrollbar and scrolling to corresponding section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/155/)

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".sections").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"light-3"});
    });
    jQuery("ul.subMenu li a").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).click(function(){
            $thisId = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $thisId.offset().top}, 'fast');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I am using mCustomScrollbar and when you click on every link it should scroll to corresponding section. But now it just jumps to clicked section no scrolling, I wrote scrolling with animate function but no success.

Comment: cant help with that but maybe you can see these sites for more ... ideas? [link1](http://callmenick.com/post/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation) or [link2](http://www.jozefbutko.com/stickynavbar/)

Comment: add swing to your animate parameter, as per to the to documentation swing will ease your animation. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @aidaghazaryan , please check this, if that's what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/NXzcx/160/

Comment: scrolling is ok swing easing is very nice, but I am using mcustomScrollbar I tried with that it doesn't work. @vivekkupadhyay

Comment: @aidaghazaryan  So you need custom scroll-able area in which you want that link ref animation effect?

Comment: yes I guess or can we do something with the scrolling that I am using?, @vivekkupadhyay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling, I got the auto-scrolling to work but I had to disable *mCustomScrollbar*, clearly not ideal. For some reason, *mCustomScrollbar* seems to interfere with *jQuery*'s `.animate()`.

So I went looking for the equivalent of `.animate()` in *mCustomScrollbar* and found this:

> **scrollTo**
>
> **Usage** $(selector).mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",position,options);
>
> Call the *scrollTo* method to **programmatically scroll the content** to the position parameter ([demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollTo_demo.html)).

[mCustomScrollbar documentation: scrollTo](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#methods-section-scrollTo)

From there, all it took was a little rewrite:

```
(function(){

    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".sections").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"light-3"});
    });

    // container ref
    var sections = $('.sections');

    $("ul.subMenu li a").each(function(){

        // link ref
        var link = $(this);

        // section ref
        var section = $(link.attr('href'));

        link.click(function(){

            sections.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", section.position().top, {

                // scroll as soon as clicked
                timeout:0,

                // scroll duration
                scrollInertia:200,
            });

            // disable original jumping
            return false;
        });
    });
})();
```

### Notes

- 200ms is the duration of the `fast` preset in *jQuery*'s `.animate()`.
  [jQuery documentation: .animate() duration](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#duration)
- We scroll the `.sections` element rather than the document.

### Demo

[mCustomScrollbar's scrollTo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/167/)

Comment: thanks much, one question I saw demo is fine but my links are something like this 'about-us/#the-team' and code isn't working, what do you think about this? @spenibus

Comment: I see, the url is not just the id then. Well, you can either parse the url with some regex or supply the id with another attribute, such as `data-target="#section-id"` and use `link.attr('data-target')`. @aidaghazaryan

Comment: thanks will try and let you know the result, @spenibus